# Find last finish task using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to find the last finish task using sql in each group. I have two conditions. `construction_type = 0` and `construction_type in (1, 2)`. For `construction_type = 0`. Only completed task will be fetch. But for `construction_type in (1, 2)`. Completed and not completed task can be fetch.  I made the query but the problem is if tasks are finish and some new task enter which is not completed then this non completed task is coming at top. I tried different order by but somehow unable to get the last completed task at top in case of
`construction_type in (1, 2)`. For `construction_type = 0` there is no problem because only the completed tasks will be fetch.

I am ordering by on task_last_modified_date. If some new task will enter then it has highest task_last_modified_date. That's why my uncompleted task is coming on top. It should be something like `latest task_last_modified_date with completed task`. But I am not sure how do I do it.

Here is the sample data

```
CREATE TABLE project_complete_data (CONSTRUCTION_TYPE, PROJECT_ID, PROJ_COMPANY_NAME,   CUSTOM_LOT_NO, LOT_STATUS, SCHEDULE_TASK_ID, TASK_NAME, TASK_STATUS, TASK_ACTUAL_END_DATE, TASK_FINISH_DATE, TASK_FINISHED, TASK_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, PO_TOTAL_AMOUNT, PO_STATUS, PO_TYPE) AS
          SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '0000000077', 102, 10961162, 'electrical rough',                     101, DATE '2021-12-13', DATE '2021-11-19', 0, TO_DATE('2021-11-16 14:44:04', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    49.7, 100, 101  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '0000000077', 102, 10961161, 'plumbing rough',                       101, DATE '2021-12-06', DATE '2021-11-12', 1, TO_DATE('2021-11-15 15:22:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    0.3,  101, 101  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '0000000077', 102, 10961159, 'roof framing',                         101, DATE '2021-11-29', DATE '2021-11-15', 1, TO_DATE('2021-11-15 13:04:37', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    10,   101, 101  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '0000000077', 102, 10961158, 'second floor framing',                 101, DATE '2021-11-15', DATE '2021-11-09', 1, TO_DATE('2021-11-09 15:22:42', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    50,   101, 101  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '0000000077', 102, 10961157, 'first floor framing',                  101, DATE '2021-11-08', DATE '2021-11-09', 1, TO_DATE('2021-11-09 14:44:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    0,    101, 101  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '0000000077', 102, 10961157, 'first floor framing',                  101, DATE '2021-11-08', DATE '2021-11-09', 1, TO_DATE('2021-11-09 14:44:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    0,    101, 101  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '01a',        103, 10134563, 'Rough-In Plumbing',                    101, DATE '2009-12-17', DATE '2014-09-01', 1, NULL,                                                       0,    100, 100  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '02',         103, 2213016,  'Update Lender Info in BT - Sales Rep', 101, DATE '2005-06-28', DATE '2005-10-11', 1, NULL,                                                       0,    100, 100  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '020',        103, 10955239, 'TK task',                              101, DATE '2018-11-07', DATE '2019-06-21', 1, TO_DATE('2019-06-21 18:12:21', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    0,    100, 101  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', '020',        103, 10955239, 'TK task',                              101, DATE '2018-11-07', DATE '2019-06-21', 1, TO_DATE('2019-06-21 18:12:21', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    33,   100, 100  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 511, 'Amber Hills Inc.', 'testpa01',   102, 10959716, 'HVAC rough',                           101, DATE '2021-09-17', DATE '2021-09-15', 0, TO_DATE('2021-11-02 12:28:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),    0,    101, 100  FROM DUAL;
```

Here is the query

```
select 
    proj_company_name, 
    custom_lot_no,
    task_name,
    task_actual_end_date,                           
    task_finish_date,
    task_finished,
    task_last_modified_date,
    to_char(task_last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AS TASK_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_TIME,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no ORDER BY to_char(task_last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc) AS LAST_TASK_FINISH_SEQ,
    po_total_amount,
    po_status,
    CASE 
        WHEN po_status = 101 THEN po_total_amount   
        ELSE 0
    END as POs_COMPLETED,
    po_type,
    CASE 
        WHEN po_type = 100 THEN po_total_amount 
        ELSE 0
    END as "COMMITTED"
FROM project_complete_data
where project_id = 511
AND po_status in ('100', '101')
AND lot_status in ('102', '103')
And task_status = 101
AND (
        (construction_type = 0 AND task_finished = 1 and (schedule_task_id is not null or schedule_task_id > 0))    
        OR (construction_type in ('1', '2') AND task_finished in ('1', '0'))                
) 
order by custom_lot_no, to_char(task_last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc;
```

This query is giving the following result

[image: result]

As you can see the top record has highest last_modified_date_time and it is coming at last_task_finish_seq at 1. But this task is not completed becasue its `task_finished is 0`. So the first record should be the second one becasue although it last_modified_date_time is less but it is completed. And it is completed in last because it has higher last_modified_date_time then other completed tasks.

How can I do it? Actually after getting each group record on top I will use some thing like

```
`select * from (above query) where LAST_TASK_FINISH_SEQ = 1;`
```

Because then I know that I have the last completed task at top of each group.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you replace `AND task_finished in ('1', '0')` with `AND task_finished ='1'` ?

Comment: @Nick I can't because then in both cases I will get the completed tasks. But in case of  `construction_type in ('1', '2')` I put `AND task_finished in ('1', '0')` so both task come. Finished and Unfinished

Comment: If you want to *first* consider only the completed tasks and *than* order on the *completion date*  use `ROW_NUMBER .... ORDER BY TASK_FINISHED desc, to_char(task_last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc`

Comment: I think I just figured it out. If I use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no, task_finished ORDER BY to_char(task_last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc) AS LAST_TASK_FINISH_SEQ,`. Then I will have two partition in each group. One for `Finished tasks` and one for `Unfinished tasks`. And then I can simply use `select * from (above query) where LAST_TASK_FINISH_SEQ = 1 and task_finished = 1`. Now I will get the last completed task from each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most recently completed row (or the latest row, if no rows are completed and `construction_type IN (1,2)`), you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   project_complete_data
  WHERE  project_id = 511
  AND    po_status IN (100, 101)
  AND    lot_status IN (102, 103)
  AND    task_status = 101
  AND    (  (   construction_type = 0
            AND task_finished = 1
            AND schedule_task_id IS NOT NULL)
         OR construction_type IN (1, 2)
         )
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY custom_lot_no
  ORDER     BY task_finished DESC, task_last_modified_date DESC
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( ^ latest_finished_row )
  DEFINE
    latest_finished_row AS 1 = 1
)
```

If you want to order the rows without filtering:

```sql
select proj_company_name, 
       custom_lot_no,
       task_name,
       task_actual_end_date,                           
       task_finish_date,
       task_finished,
       task_last_modified_date,
       to_char(task_last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
         AS TASK_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_TIME,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY custom_lot_no
         ORDER BY task_finished DESC, task_last_modified_date desc
       ) AS LAST_TASK_FINISH_SEQ,
       po_total_amount,
       po_status,
       CASE 
       WHEN po_status = 101
       THEN po_total_amount   
       ELSE 0
       END as POs_COMPLETED,
       po_type,
       CASE 
       WHEN po_type = 100
       THEN po_total_amount 
       ELSE 0
       END as "COMMITTED"
FROM   project_complete_data
where  project_id = 511
AND    po_status  in (100, 101)
AND    lot_status in (102, 103)
And    task_status = 101
AND    (  (   construction_type = 0
          AND task_finished = 1 
          AND schedule_task_id is not null
          )    
       OR (   construction_type in (1, 2)
          AND task_finished in (1, 0)
          ) 
) 
order by custom_lot_no, task_last_modified_date desc;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f58462cae93d5440005767ed492f3379)*